# Who designed the Life Magazine in 1936? Who was responsible for the whole visual look of the magazine?

Tags: art, history, editorial-design

I can't find any editorial designers from the period 1930-1950, who worked for that magazine. Who created the logo? who made all those decissions in design?

Even other important 1930s graphic designer would be nice to hear.

Answer (score 2):

Designers are notoriously not given any credit of merit. You'll probably have to find an old copy and look at the publishing notes to find the staff member with the actual title of "Designer" or "graphic Designer".

https://oldlifemagazine.com/vintage-magazines-by-year/the-1930s/1936.html

However Life magazine was created by **Henry Luce**. Luce was a *publisher/editor*, and not a designer. However, as editor, *he* was responsible for the "look and feel" of the publication. This is why Designers don't generally get any real credit — they follow the art direction of the Editor where magazines are concerned.

https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/first-issue-of-life-is-published

<sub>(I have always found it odd that photography credit is essentially an "automatic" for anything. However designer credit never seems to be given the slightest consideration. That is unless *that* particular designer went on to become notable in the profession in the future — Glaser, Bass, etc. — but they didn't get any credit at the time of the design initially.)</sub>

---

As for designers or design in the 30s, [a simple internet search](https://www.google.com/search?q=famous+1930+graphic+designers&ei=r5GmYvqzPP3CkPIPx5q9EA&ved=0ahUKEwi6x46koqn4AhV9IUQIHUdNDwIQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=famous+1930+graphic+designers&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQuAxY7BVgnxpoAnABeACAAXyIAfAFkgEDMi41mAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) for that will turn up far more information than I can convey here.

Comment: Thank you so much for that detailed and precise answer!